# How to deserialize JSON to class using SubTypes by multiple properties?

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "type": "cat",
  "subType": "flufy",
   ...
}
```

and I have the following classes:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"),
        ...
})
public abstract class Animal {
    public AnimalType type;
    public AnimalSubType subType;
    public String name;
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
}

public class FlufyAnimal extends Animal {
}
```

and I need deserialize JSON at the following conditions:
- if `type` equals cat and `subType` equals flufy have to deserialize JSON to `FlufyAnimal` class, if `type` equals dog have to deserialize to `Dog` class.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well briefly it must looks like this:

```
public class AnimalDesiarializer extends JsonDeserializer<Animal> {

  @Override
  public Animal deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
      throws IOException {
    ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
    String type = node.get("type").asText();
    String subType = node.get("subType").asText();
    if (Objects.equals(type, "cat") && Objects.equals(subType, "FlufyAnimal")) {
      return new Cat(type, subType);
    } else {
      return new Dog(type, subType);
    }
  }
}
```

But you must pay an attention that according to your models not all the `FluffyAnimal`s are cats)